# Postfix: Filtering Outgoing Mail According to Sender Subnet

Tags: linux, email, postfix, filtering

I need some specific LAN subnets to send e-mail to only my corporate domain such as printers or kiosks. How it could be possible via Postfix?

Comment: yes, it worked as I explained below.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set up different instances of postfix with the listener in the subnet, set mynetworks to be that subnet, don't allow mail from elsewhere, set the corporate mail domain as a valid relay domain. This is quite simple with `check_sender_access`.
2. Create an [allowed sender group](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html), with `check_sender_access` you can allow or disallow by IP or subnet also. Have a look at the [access documentation](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) for more information

Answer (score 1):

thanks. here is the steps that worked for me:

in main.cf

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
      check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/check_client_access
```

in check_client_access

```
192.168.9       OK
192.168         REJECT
```

and then,

`postmap /etc/postfix/check_client_access`

`service postfix restart`